# How can I reduce/ignore any damage reduction with weapon attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage-reduction

How can I reduce/ignore any damage reduction with weapon attacks?

I know the Mountain Hammer line from Tome of Battle:

> As part of this maneuver, you make a single melee attack. This attack deals an extra 2d6 points of damage and automatically overcomes damage reduction and hardness.

I am looking for a way to get this effect of overcoming damage reduction on a full-attack.

I *think* I have seen a "reduce any DR by 5" feat, but I can't remember where.

Permanent solutions are preferable, and official books.

Comment: I take it that obeying the conditions of the DR in question, i.e. defeating DR 10/silver by using a silvered weapon, is not the answer you’re looking for?

Comment: Any and all content is fair game? Also, are you looking for permanent, or are psionics also fair game?

Comment: Thing is, I think I know what you're after, but the question's currently asked in such a way that were I to offer a list of stuff I think you want, I suspect other readers would ding the answer as incomplete or shallow. That is, I think you want ways for a creature to reduce or ignore DR without its foe's involvement, such as *You bypass DR* instead of *You bypass this enemy creature's DR.* As is, for instance, an answer  that says *Use spells* is perfectly reasonable. Consider rephrasing the question if I've assessed it correctly.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the part about weapon attacks you mentioned in the body, and I've added a quote from Mountain Hammer so people can get a better idea what kind of effect you are looking for, that should prevent a lot of the confusion you're getting now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Mythic Examplar (Complete Champion p.88)

A character who takes the 10th level of the **Mythic Examplar** prestige class who follow the Sunyartra paragon can ignore 15 points of any damage reduction, except epic damage reduction. This ability is permanent and constant.

You can additionally overcome epic damage reduction simply by wielding a +6 or better weapon.

Alternatively, the spell *vulnerability* (*Draconomicon* p.115) reduces a creature's damage reduction by 5 points, and another 5 points for every four caster levels beyond 11th. It can only reduce to a minimum of 5.

#### Feats

After consulting the [feat index](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/feats) for references to damage reduction, I'm reasonably certain there's no *feat* which reduces damage reduction.

There are feats which will let your attacks ignore specific types of damage reduction: Aligned Attack (*Expanded Psionics Handbook*, p.41) and *Improved Smiting* (*Complete Divine*, p.82) can bypass alignment DR; Penetrating Damage Reduction (*Epic Level Handbook*, p.63), following the [3.5 update](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/dnd/20030718a), bypasses one material type of DR and can be taken multiple times, and Improved Ki Strike (*Epic Level Handbook*, p.58) bypasses on unarmed attacks only, although perhaps there is a prestige class somewhere that allows Ki Strike with weapons.

#### Other partial solutions

A sword called the **Nightblade of Arvandor** (*Book of Exalted Deeds* p.115) lets you make ranged attacks which ignore all damage reduction as they're technically magical force effects.

The **Infused (Lantern Archon)** (Dragon #321), at 7th level of this prestige class, can shoot light rays which ignore damage reduction of any type.

The **Forsaker** (*Masters of the Wild*) can ignore damage reduction of any form he himself has. However, that was a 3.0 book, and the Forsaker was not officially updated to 3.5, where the damage reduction rules are very different.

The **Ring of Elemental Command** (*Dungeon Master's Guide*) allows a weapon to bypass the damage reduction of any creature from the elemental plane to which it is attuned.

The **Golembane Scarab** (*Dungeon Master's Guide*) allows a weapon to ignore the damage reduction of golems.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, a **Blade of Ragnarok** (Epic Destinies) has a feature called *Blade of Ruin (Su)* which allows you to treat your weapon as whatever you need to overcome a certain DR - e.g. aligned, epic, silver, piercing, magic. The limitation is, only one such effect can be active at a given time. (Which IMO is a tad weak for epic levels, but that type of content has always been a crapshoot. There is a non-epic variant for these however, where they replace the feats starting at L12.)